# How to select between two values, using one 60% of the times and the other 40% of the time

Tags: python

I'm sorry for the really shitty title but i cant explain it better in a short way.

What im trying to do is to create a generator that generates people. i want the user to be able to specify how many men vs women there should be.
Right now i set gender by

```
gender = random.randint(1, 2)
```

where 1 = male and 2 = female.
lets say i want to create 100 people where 60% of them are women, how do i keep track of it?
my code right

```
    while count != num_of_names:
    l_num = random.randint(0, 149)
    f_num = random.randint(0, 200)
    f_name_male = f_names_males[f_num]
    f_name_female = f_names_females[f_num]
    gender = random.randint(1, 2)
    if gender == 1:
        f_name = f_name_male
    else:
        f_name = f_name_female
    l_name = l_names[l_num]
    names.append((f_name, l_name, gender))
    count += 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I "randomly" select numbers with a specified bias toward a particular number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507558/how-do-i-randomly-select-numbers-with-a-specified-bias-toward-a-particular-num)

Comment: Hm interesting, well that would work to some extent but im looking for a solution that limits the amounts. if i would have used that np.randomchoice with 60% bias towards men i could still end up with more or less than 60%. im looking for a solution that gives me the exact distribution i specify. if i want to create 100 people with 60/40 distribution M/F i want 60 males and 40 females.

Comment: Then use a loop to create 60 males and a second loop to create 40 females. If needed shuffle the resulting list after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) and call it to randomise a list. Here is a generator that yields random values 'M' or "F' from a fixed pool in the relative amounts requested:

```
import random

def gender(n_male, n_female):
    population = list('M' * n_male + 'F' * n_female)
    random.shuffle(population)
    for i in range(len(population)):
        yield population[i]

>>> l = [g for g in gender(40, 60)]
>>> assert l.count('M') == 40
>>> assert l.count('F') == 60
>>> print(f"male : {l.count('M')}, female : {l.count('F')}")
male : 40, female : 60

>>> l = [g for g in gender(50, 50)]
>>> print(f"male : {l.count('M')}, female : {l.count('F')}")
male : 50, female : 50
```

Comment: thanks, im trying this out. but the result i get back is <function gender at 0x0000021F19C0F940> not an actual value. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Warmupp: `gender` is a generator function. If you bind the result to a variable, or just call it, it will return a generator object. If you want the results in a list then you must consume items from it, as shown in the example: `l = [g for g in gender(40, 60)]`. You asked for a generator, perhaps not being aware that in Python a generator is a special type of function. If you just want a plain old function, add `return random.shuffle(population)` and remove the `yield` for loop.

Comment: TIL, ill read up on it. thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to always have an exact distribution, just create the list and use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) to randomize the values within the list.

```
from random import shuffle

gender = [1] * 40 + [2] * 60
shuffle(gender)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```
gender_array = ["Male" if x > 60 else "Female" for x in range(0, 100)]
gender = gender_array[random.randint(0, len(gender_array))]
print(gender)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came to this solution

```
import random

population = []
    
def generate_sex(no_of_generate_people, percent): 
    
    male = "male"
    female = "female"

    ratio = no_of_generate_people * percent    
    
    for i in range(no_of_generate_people):
        if float(population.count("male")) > float(ratio):
                population.append("female")
        else:
            population.append("male") 

        if len(population) > no_of_generate_people:
            return population

generate_sex(100, 0.7)

print(population.count("male"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a few small functions and tie them together:

```
def random_male():
    return (random.choice(f_names_male), random.choice(l_names), 'male')

def random_female():
    return (random.choice(f_names_female), random.choice(l_names), 'female')

def random_males(amount):
    return [random_male() for _ in range(amount)]

def random_females(amount):
    return [random_female() for _ in range(amount)]

def random_people(males, females):
    return random_males(males) + random_females(females)
```

or even

```
def make_stuff(generator, amount):
    return [generator() for _ in range(amount)]

def make_people(males, females):
    return make_stuff(random_male, males) + make_stuff(random_female, females)
```